# TypeScript compiles, but gives a runtime error

Tags: typescript

I am very new to TypeScript and I've run into a problem that I can't quite figure out...

I am using a library called TypeLite that will take my C# POCO's and convert them into TypeScript classes.

It is a T4 template that generates a file called TypeLite.Net4.d.ts, which as I understand, .d files are definition files that are loaded automatically.

The generated code looks like this:

```
declare module Models {
    export class LoginModel {
        password: string;
        rememberMe: boolean;
        userName: string;
    }
}
```

In my component, I can access Models.LoginModel just fine and it doesn't give me any compiler errors (using Visual Studio).

However, when I try and run it, I get:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: Models is not defined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ReferenceError: Models is not defined
    at new LoginComponent
```

Here is my LoginComponent:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './app/login/login.html'
})

export class LoginComponent {
    model: Models.LoginModel = new Models.LoginModel();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have not imported Model into your LoginComponent

```
   import { Model } from 'path to Model module';
```

The intellisense you might be getting because of the definition file, but to use it at run time you have to import the class.